# Saml2Assertion to XML is empty

Tags: c#, xml, soap, certificate, saml

I try to make an HttpWebRequest with a SOAP data, and in the SOAP header, I will have to add a SAML 2 Assertion, that contains a certificate from Windows Certificate Store.

So I made my assertion this way :

```
Saml2Assertion oSAMLAssertion =
  new Saml2Assertion (
    new Saml2NameIdentifier (oPSCertificate.Subject)
  );
oSAMLAssertion.Id = new Saml2Id ();
oSAMLAssertion.IssueInstant = DateTime.Now;

oSAMLAssertion.Subject =
  new Saml2Subject (new Saml2NameIdentifier ("CPS") { Value = sPSID });

oSAMLAssertion.Statements
  .Add (
    new Saml2AttributeStatement (
      new Saml2Attribute ("identifiantFacturation", sIDFact)
    ));
oSAMLAssertion.Statements
  .Add (
    new Saml2AttributeStatement (
      new Saml2Attribute ("codeSpecialiteAMO", sCodeSpec)
    ));

oSAMLAssertion.SigningCredentials =
  new X509SigningCredentials (oPSCertificate);
```

No problem. But when I want the XML of this assertion to add to my SOAP request, I proceed like that :

```
StringBuilder oXML = new StringBuilder ();
XmlWriter oXMLSerializer = XmlWriter.Create (
  oXML,
  new XmlWriterSettings () { ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment }
);
Saml2SecurityToken o = new Saml2SecurityToken (oSAMLAssertion);
o2.WriteToken (oXMLSerializer, o);
```

But my oXML.ToString return empty, I don't have the XML...
I checked the .NET sources references to see if I miss something and it seems not, I should have my XML ...

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To Get the XML output the Saml2Assertion needs to have signedcredenitials otherwise xml will be blank.

```
X509Certificate2 cert =null;
var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);

store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

X509Certificate2 cert =null;

foreach (var certificate in store.Certificates)
{
    if (certificate.Thumbprint=="ffffff")
        { cert = certificate; }
}

store.Close();

var assertion = new Saml2Assertion(new Saml2NameIdentifier("Name"))
    .SigningCredentials = new X509SigningCredentials(cert);


StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
var settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
settings.Indent = false;
settings.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

var stringWriter = new StringWriter(sb);
var responseWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter, settings); 

new Saml2Serializer().WriteSaml2Assertion(responseWriter, assertion);

public class Saml2Serializer : Saml2SecurityTokenHandler
{
    public Saml2Serializer()
    {
        Configuration = new SecurityTokenHandlerConfiguration()
        {};
    }

public void WriteSaml2Assertion(XmlWriter writer, Saml2Assertion data)
{
    try
    { base.WriteAssertion(writer, data); }
    catch (Exception e)
    { System.Console.Write(e.StackTrace); }      
}

    public void WriteSaml2Token(XmlWriter writer, Saml2SecurityToken data)
    {
        try
        { base.WriteToken(writer, data); }
        catch (Exception e)
        { System.Console.Write(e.StackTrace); }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this helped me "needs to have signedcredenitials". I did not have a signed credential. I added a signed credential and it worked for me!

Comment: This is it. And I have to create my signature method for my own puprpose. Thanks

Comment: Am I the only one having a problem here?  

This line of code 

var assertion=new Saml2Assertion(new      Saml2NameIdentifier("Name")).SigningCredentials = new X509SigningCredentials(cert);

Returns a SigningCredentials not a Saml2Assertion and therefore WriteSaml2Assertion is the wrong signature.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a stringwriter wrapper between the xml writer. Change this:

```
XmlWriter oXMLSerializer = XmlWriter.Create(oXML, new XmlWriterSettings() { ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment });
```

to:

```
using (StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter(oXML))
using (XmlWriter oXMLSerializer = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter, new XmlWriterSettings() { OmitXmlDeclaration = true, Encoding = Encoding.UTF8 }))
{
    Saml2SecurityToken o = new Saml2SecurityToken(oSAMLAssertion);
    o2.WriteToken(oXMLSerializer, o);
}
```

Comment: You need to call oXMLSerializer.Flush() or wrap in using statements. I updated the code example.

Comment: Unfortunaly, doesn't change anything... I write the assertion myself using XElement and SignedXml for this situtation